# Breeze controller side entity update not working

Tags: breeze

I am using BeforeSaveEntity event of the to initialize coordinates (latitude, longitude) information from the third party service.

I convert the EntityInfo.Entity in required destination type and I update the value in it. However when it goes to saveChanges() method it does not push my updated values to the database.

I assume somehow the context cannot track the modification I made to the entity.

Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess here but in Breeze v 1.1.3 we added a the **EntityInfo.ForceUpdate** boolean property but it never made it into the main Breeze documentation, it only appeared in the release notes.

This property may be used to force a server side update of an entire entity when server side modification has been made to any property of an existing entity. The other approach that may be used is to  explicitly update the EntityInfo.OriginalValuesMap.

The idea behind both of these is that on an update Breeze only creates an update statement for those se properties that have been changed.  Any client side changes are automatically detected because of Breeze's tracking mechanism which adds an entry into an 'originalValuesMap', but this cannot be done automatically for server side changes because the server side entities are not instrumented to perform notification about property changes.

Comment: Thank you! That did the job. I updated EntityInfo.OrignalValuesMap before updating entity on server side.